# XSLT contains() not working

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use contains() where i want to display the node value only when it does not contain number but I get all the node values in result. Below is my code and sample XML. My code is as below: Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

my code:

```
     <xsl:variable name="restricted_characters" select="1234567890"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="test/a">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(. , $restricted_characters))">
         <xsl:value-of select="position()" />:
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

XML:

```
    <test>
    <a>abc11</a>
    <a>123</a>
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>abc2</a>
    <a>abc3</a>
    <a>abc</a>
    </test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way. `contains()` checks if the 1st argument contains the 2nd argument *entirely*. For example, your test expression will return *true* for `abc1234567890` but *false* for `abc123`.

Instead of using `contains()`, you can use `translate()` to replace number characters in your input string with empty, and then compare the result against the original input string. If both are the same, then that means the input string doesn't contain any number characters.

```
<xsl:if test="translate(. , $restricted_characters, '') != .">
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation and solution.